# Is it possible Input::all() codigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am finding Input::all() function in laravel.If any function avaliable in codeigniter

```
Laravel code:
 $my_data=Input::all();
$basicdetails=\DB::table('user_profile') ->insert($my_data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$myData = $this->input->post(); //for post request
```

or

```
 $myData = $this->input->get(); //for get request
```